# oracle: sysdate as timestamp while the time is 00:00:00.0

Tags: sql, oracle, date, time, timestamp

I need get the sysdate in format timestamp  while the time will be: 00:00:00.0

example for today:
2014-07-24 00:00:00.000000

How to make it?

Below the current code. what to change?

```
declare
  v_t timestamp; 
begin
  v_t := to_timestamp(systimestamp);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_t);
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the time portion of a timestamp you can use the `TRUNC()` function:

```
...
v_t := to_timestamp(trunc(systimestamp));
...
```

Be aware that the TIMESTAMP datatype by itself does not have a *format*, so printing a timestamp will produce the format dependent on you locale setting. To ensure certain formatting you'd need to use the `TO_CHAR()` function with the appropriate format string.

Comment: @AlexPoole -- it is redundant, of course, but that's what the OP has.

Comment: @AlexPoole -- by the way, if the result must have fractional seconds, the `to_timestamp()` is _not_ redundant, because `trunc()` returns a `DATE` data type, which _does not_ have fractional seconds.

Comment: D'oh, of course it does... sorry, brain failure! (It's redundant in the OP's version, which may be partly what confused me. Easily done though). It's still doing implicit conversions to and from a string though, so it's vulnerable to NLS issues - I'd probably use `cast` <shrug>